# How to NOT commit locally deleted files to git

Tags: git

We have a situation where were are using git to stash myriad scans (images) and do not wish to preserve them on the local machine once set on up; however, git is seeing each local deletion (following this process) as something to be committed up to the repo, and we want that not to happen.  Any ideas on how to commit only the additional files and never any deletions?

Comment: I have a hunch that Git may not be the ideal tool for your problem.

Comment: You're almost certainly correct; but I'm not in charge of that choice just yet.  =(

Comment: By any chance, do you happen to have a filesystem path to the upstream repo?

Answer (score 3):

### Use the Skip-Worktree Bit

The [git-update-index(1)](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-update-index.html) command provides some ways of dealing with this. Based on the assumption that you want to keep the blobs in your history while deleting them from your working tree, you could use the following:

```
git add --all
git commit --message="Add new assets to repository."
git update-index update-index --skip-worktree <files ...>
rm <files ...>
```

Note that the last line isn't a Git command because you're removing the files from the working tree *in the shell* after you've stored them in the index. Don't use `git rm` by mistake, because it operates on the index.

### Listing Your Special Bits and Index-Only Files

To see the files you've marked with the skip-worktree bit:

```
git ls-files -v | awk -v IGNORECASE=1 '$1 ~ /s/ {print}'
```

You can also use [git-ls-files(1)](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-ls-files.html) to find files in the index that have been removed from your working tree.

Answer (score 2):

For each file to be deleted, do this:

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged <file>
```

This should stop Git from asking you to commit the deletion.

That being said, perhaps a better solution would be to use SFTP with permissions set to disallow deleting or modifying files once uploaded.

Comment: ooh; I shall play with this

Comment: Do you have to do this for every commit?

Comment: You have to do it for each file, I think.

Comment: Once done, is it lasting, or will I have to do that for each file every time a new commit is done?

Comment: I've poked at it a little bit and update-index doth appear to be persistent ... can it eventually get too big to function well?

Answer (score 1):

(edit: package up the payload as a self-contained script)

You're after a nearly status-only local repository that tracks the existence of everything you've ever created but keeps the contents of only the most recent stuff (after pushing everything upstream).  Presuming you never reuse a pathname, here's the ritual:

**One-time setup:**

Create and push an `everything` branch that tracks every image you've got so far.  Base a (local-only) `worktree` branch off that.

```
git checkout -b everything     # this will be the branch you push
git push origin everything     # .
git checkout -b worktree       # you'll stay on this branch
```

**Work (almost) as if you didn't want to do anything special:**

Everything that needs preserving upstream is on the `everything` branch, and you've got `worktree` checked out.  Remove images you're done with from the worktree, make new images there that need pushing, and commit the new worktree state:

```
# work work:
rm -r anything/ you\'re/ done with
create new images
git add -A .  # good gitignore patterns make life easy
git commit
```

To do the requested work, run

```
merge-push-and-cleanup   # the script below
```

After which everything's stored upstream, nothing redundant remains locally, and you're ready for more work.

---

**The `merge-push-and-cleanup` script:**

```
#!/bin/sh
# Git can do "index-only" merges when the content doesn't need to be examined,
# you can casually create sideband indexes, and `git commit-tree` works on any 
# tree in the repo.

  (
# ^ subshell to keep G_I_F export local
  export GIT_INDEX_FILE=.git/sideband-index

  # make a merged index that includes everything from both branches, by
  # starting from an empty merge base so all files show up as additions.

  git read-tree -im $(git mktree </dev/null) worktree everything

  # commit to the `everything` branch straight from the constructed index,
  # reusing the commit message from `worktree`

  git cat-file -p worktree | sed 1,/^$/d \
  | git commit-tree -p everything -p worktree $(git write-tree --missing-ok) \
  | xargs git update-ref refs/heads/everything
)

git push origin everything

# preserve the branch metadata and, just for safety, your latest images
# by packing it all up:

mkdir -p .git/preserved/pack
rm -f .git/preserved/pack/*
(
  git rev-list worktree everything
  git rev-parse worktree^{tree} everything^{tree}
  git ls-tree -rt worktree | awk '{ print $3 }'
  git ls-tree -rt everything | awk '$2 != "blob" { print $3 }'
) \
| git pack-objects .git/preserved/pack/pack

# now for the fun one:
rm -rf .git/objects/*   # !!!

# put the preserved stuff back:
mv .git/preserved/pack .git/objects
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add images to gitignore. You do not need to store them in repo, right?

Comment: Actually, this particular repo is specifically for said images; the issue is once they go up, they're removed from the local and we don't want the deletion to subsequently be committed.  The other guy said git is probably not ideal for this, but alternatives to git simply was not tabled to us as a possible solution, so whee.  *shrug*